# SVN commit using Jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, command, commit

I recently created an automated process to run multi-step Maven builds for my organization. They now are looking to have the entire process automated using Jenkins. I have been able to successfully create branches, builds, change versions, etc., using Maven commands but I am having difficulty committing the version changes (1.0.1-Snapshot to 1.0.1-E1 for example) with Jenkins. I have tried using basic commands like:

SVN commit  "Comments"

However, Jenkins does not seem to know what to do with these command lines in the "Execute Windows Batch File" Post Build option. I simply receive build failures caused by the batch file for "unknown reasons." I see the help desk I am working with has installed the Subversion plugin, but perhaps something else is missing. I know that when I use the command prompt locally I need to use something like this:

"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" 
/command:commit /path: /url:

However, Jenkins is hosted by a third party and I do not have direct access to the servers so I would not be able to implement that kind of path data. So I am now looking to see if I can run this, somehow, purely through Jenkins as my client requests.

Anyone have any success with SVN Commit to update version changes through Jenkins?

Thanks!

-Cameron

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide to run [`TortoiseProc`](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) via Jenkins? TortoiseProc is not the right tool for this task, use `svn.exe` client.

TortoiseProc can be used for TortoiseSVN's GUI automation, but this case is completely different to running Jenkins.